# Dijkstra's algorithm in c when vertex that are not connected has the value of -1 using Matrix of weights

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, dijkstra

im trying to implement the Dijkstra's algorithm in c when vertex that are not connected has the value of -1 using Matrix of weights.

Graph- https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjOwM.png
Weight matrix - https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYu3z.png

my code working if i use the the "-1" value as some int value(bigger then all the edges weight) but i need to support all int values(0 and positive)

how can i change the following code in order to support the -1 as infinity value and that the code will work!

p.s -1 value is for example the connection between 3 to 4
the weight matrix in in size of 6 and starts from index 1 and not 0

thanks alot...

```
while(selected[target] ==0)
{
    min = INT_MAX;
    m = 0;
    for(i=1;i< size;i++)
    {
        d = dist[start] +cost[start][i];
        if(d< dist[i]&&selected[i]==0)
        {
            dist[i] = d;
            prev[i] = start;
        }
        if(min>dist[i] && selected[i]==0)
        {
            min = dist[i];
            m = i;
        }
    }
    start = m;
    selected[start] = 1;
}
start = target;
j = 0;
while(start != -1)
{
    path[j++] = start;
    start = prev[start];
}


return pathList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check that an edge does not have -1 weight:

```
for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (cost[start][i] != -1) {
        d = dist[start] + cost[start][i];
        if (d < dist[i] && selected[i] == 0) {
            dist[i] = d;
            prev[i] = start;
        }
    }
    if (min > dist[i] && selected[i] == 0) {
        min = dist[i];
        m = i;
    }
}
```

By the way, if you need to support edge weights up to `INT_MAX`, you should  store distances in a 64-bit integer type to prevent overflow.